# Find elements in a table from a td that has an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I have this question

I have this structure:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td id="id1"><td>
         <td><td>
         <td><td>
         <td><td>
      </tr>
      ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the td id and I want to find the table element. Then I want to find, change and show/hide the 4-th **tr**, but I can't.

I tried `$("td#id1")` and it finds the td but how can I use it to get the table element and then the 4-th row. They have no IDs.

Another problem I must not change the structure in any way, no new IDs can be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) along with [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("td#id1").closest('table').find('tr:eq(3)').show(); // or hide() here
```

Comment: tried that: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'closest'

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: yes that was the first thing I checked, I also tried .parents(...) still the same, everything else works. No errors in the console